# Is it OK to use an environment variable as version to build a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, continuous-deployment

I want to ease the deployment of an internal gem to our private Github rubygems registry. Most of the time, within the gemspec file, the version is hardcoded or read from another file. Meaning to publish a new release once your code base ready, you have to create a pull request, modified the version, merge, then finally publish.

This workflow does not match the other services in our monorepo. For these last, once we want to release, we create a branch *release/service-name/v1.2* that trigger a [Github Deployment](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/deployments) and a dedicated CI pipeline where we can retrieve the name of the version to release.

So for our gem, I was thinking to use an environment variable to set the version when calling gem build *rubocop-xxxxx* like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  spec.name = 'rubocop-xxxxx'
  spec.metadata = {
    'github_repo' => 'ssh://github.com/xxxxx/monorepo',
    'allowed_push_host' => 'https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/xxxxx',
    'source_code_uri' => 'https://github.com/xxxxx/monorepo/tree/main/packages/common/rubocop'
  }
  spec.version = ENV['PACKAGE_RELEASE_VERSION'] || "0.0.0"
  spec.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 2.7'

  spec.files = Dir[
    'rubocop.yml',
    'conf/**/*',
    '*.gemspec',
    'Gemfile',
  ]

  spec.add_dependency('rubocop-performance', '~> 1.13.3')
  spec.add_dependency('rubocop-rails', '~> 2.14.2')
  spec.add_dependency('rubocop-rake', '~> 0.6.0')
  spec.add_dependency('rubocop-rspec', '~> 2.9.0')
  spec.add_dependency('rubocop-shopify', '~> 2.5.0')
end
```

The *0.0.0* fallback is here to avoid issue when generating the *Gemfile.lock* when running `bundle install`.

Is it OK to have such gemspec, or can I see later some issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would **not** use an environment variable for setting the gem version.

If your goal is to test a release candidate of `rubocop-xxxxx` gem in one of your service before you finally release it, you can use the `path` [option](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/gemfile.5.html#PATH) in the `Gemfile` instead of releasing each change.

**Example**

Gemfile:

```
gem "rubocop-xxxxx", path: <path-to-the-gem>
```

When the version of the gem works as expected, release it (with a hard-coded version number), remove the `path` option from the `Gemfile` again and specify the released `version` instead.

**Example**

Gemfile:

```
gem "rubocop-xxxxx", "~> 1.1"
```

Comment: The path option was our genuine choice, we migrate then to the git option and finally we jump on "true" gem. 
My purpose is not test the gem but just to publish it once ready keeping the workflow as described into my original question.
What’s your cons about env var for such situation?